# anyone else got this problem while using JSON view format? List items not showing after the 30th row?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I tried it several times with chrome whenever am at the 30th the row in the list it stops showing the rest of the rows.

When I inspect element browser it loads the rest of the rows or when I move the mouse several times up and down in the scroll bar.

Comment: What is the item limit set in view settings? Can you please add the JSON code your are using to your question? Also, I have seen similar issues at [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/json-list-view-format-doesn-t-load-all-items/m-p/1321674) and [here](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/issues/108). Check this if it helps.

Comment: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/view-samples/contact-card-format/contact-card-format.json

Answer (score 0):

Please share the element you are using so that we will know which one is causing the problem.

And if you are using the style format `float` when building tile/card view, then yes, it is a known issue which display only the first 30 items after page refreshing (reporting posts can be referred in Ganesh Sanap’s comment).

Here is a workaround for the mentioned issue: [How to create a Tile view on modern SharePoint lists.](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2019/09/11/how-to-create-a-tile-view-on-modern-sharepoint-lists/)

I haven’t found other elements causing the same issue. Please do update in this thread if you are using another one.

Comment: no am using flexbox for style, all the code is in here https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/view-samples/contact-card-format/contact-card-format.json

Comment: @draco00 Thanks for sharing. Have tested the sample though, it shows all items as you described, just not for the first time and takes a few scrolling down the page. That’s different from the reports we provided which shows the first 30 items no matter what. I’m not sure if it will be considered as a bug or not.